# Fourier transform of a confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: hypergeometric-function, fourier-transform

I have the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {_1 F_1}(a;b;cx^2)e^{i k x} dx
\end{equation}
basically, this is just a Fourier transform. I tried looking this up in some table of integrals and some table of Fourier transforms but I couldn't find anything.

How do I evaluate this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions, equation 13.10.12, gives the value

$$
\frac1{\Gamma(b)} \int_0^\infty \cos(2 x t) \cdot {}_1 F_1(a, b, -t^2) dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\Gamma(a)} x^{2a-1} e^{-x^2} U(b-\tfrac12, a+\tfrac12, x^2)
$$

where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind. This expression can be rewritten to suit your needs, provided that $c<0$, by a suitable change of variables in $x$ and $t$.